# Patching python's logging handlers

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I'm writing unit tests to make sure that my log messages for syslog are limited in size. In particular, my Formatter is set like this:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler
[...]
default_fmt = logging.Formatter(
    '%(name)s:%(levelname)s - %(message).{}s'.format(MAX_LOG_MESSAGE_SIZE)
)
```

All that I want to know is that the **final** message is less than a certain number of characters. I assumed I needed to patch `SysLogHandler` like this:

```
with patch('mylib.logger.logging.handlers.SysLogHandler') as m:
    import mylib.logger
    msg = 'foo'
    mylib.logger.debug(msg)
    print m.mock_calls
    print m.call_list()
```

However running the tests with `nosetests` doesn't work:

> ImportError: No module named logging

What am I forgetting?

Comment: The `ImportError` suggests that the Python interpreter is unable to find the `logging` module. Are you using a pre-2.3 Python by chance? Otherwise, I'm stumped...

Comment: @Kendas I'm on python 2.7.9. Yes, it's quite odd.